# Подключение вместо проброса порта Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, portforwarding

Есть два ubuntu-сервера в одной сети. При выполнении команды `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 server` для проброса порта mysql с сервера происходит не проброс, а ssh-подключение к серверу. В чём дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несмотря на подключение, порт всё равно должен пробрасываться. В крайнем случае можно добавить в конце флаг `-N` чтобы было `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 server -N`. Данный флаг указывает, что нужно пробросить порт без выполнения ssh-команды (в данном случае без подключения к серверу).

Comment: некорректно вы сформулировали. подключение к серверу, конечно же, происходит. просто не запускается login shell.